# Not propperly routing in reversed proxy Laravel App

Tags: laravel, apache, web, reverse-proxy

I have configurated an Apache Server which uses reverse proxy to show a web app developed in laravel and mounted in another apache web server. Let's say that the domain is `myapp.app`
Which works properly, but when I click to a subdomain, let's say `myapp.app/register` the browser returns `myapp.appregister/`.

At the moment I've configurated my webserver as it follows:

```
  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
             SSLEngine On
             ServerName myapp.app
             <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
             </Proxy>
             <Location "/">
                RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
                RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl on
                RequestHeader set X-Url-Scheme https
             </Location>
             ProxyPreserveHost on
             ProxyPass         /        http://172.31.0.234/
             ProxyPassReverse  /        http://172.31.0.234/
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias www.redes-erdica.tech
SSLCertificateFile /***.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /***.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
             ServerName myapp.app
             Redirect permanent / https://myapp.app/
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And the config file for the inner apache server has no other configurations besides the location of the laravel Project. Some curious event that happens is that if I type manually `myapp.app/register` it sends me where it should be, so why the browser sends me in a wrong direct when I click in the register button?

In addition, the app in localserver works properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the main configuration file located on the /etc/apache2 folder, you need to change the value of the section AllowOveride that points to the folder on which your aplication lives and change it like this:

```
    <Directory [your_app_folder]
       Options ...
       AllowOverride All
       Require ...
    </Directory>
```